# Block " and ' from being entered in an input field

Tags: php, string

I got such simple code:

```
    private function edit_keywords($text)
{
    $tresc = str_replace("\n","",$text);
    $tresc = str_replace("\r","",$text);
    if(strpos($text,'"')!==FALSE)
    {
        array_push($this->warnings,"Not allowed character found in keywords \".");
        return;
    }
```

Currently this will block **"** from being entered I would like to block **'** too. How to do this ?

Replacing ' would be fine too.

Comment: That's a very odd limit on allowed characters. Why are you just forbidding the quote characters found in ASCII?

Comment: I don't know what to say. You have code that checks for `"`, can't you use the same to check for `'`? You have code that replaces `\n` and `\r`, can't use use the same to replace `'`?

Comment: Just remember: ALL CLIENT SIDE CHECKS are EASILY bypassed, so ALL validation MUST be re-checked on the server

Comment: @Adam He *is* checking server-side.

Comment: @meagar Oh right. I've been looking at a lot of client side JS validation recently and so my mind is in the wrong place

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write a second `strpos` check for single quotes, either using double quotes (`"'"`) or by escaping the single quote: `'\''`.

```
if(strpos($text,'\'')!==FALSE)
{
    array_push($this->warnings,"Not allowed character found in keywords \".");
    return;
}
```

Eventually, you may reach the level of complexity where you want to store all the characters you want to test for in an array, and iterate over them, rather than continually appending new `if` statements:

```
$bad_chars = array('"', '\'');

foreach ($bad_chars as $bad_char) {
  if (strpos($text, $bad_char) !== false) {
    array_push($this->warnings,"Not allowed character found in keywords \".");
    return; # or break, to stop after the first disallowed characte
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<?php

private function edit_keywords($text)
{
    $tresc = str_replace("\n","",$text);
    $tresc = str_replace("\r","",$text);

    if ((strpos($text,'"')!==FALSE)||(strpos($text,"'")!==FALSE))
    {
        array_push($this->warnings,"Not allowed character found in keywords \".");
        return;
    }

?>
```

Comment: I think your logical AND (`&&`) should be an OR (`||`)

Comment: Surely you'd want an || instead of && ?

Comment: @AdamBatkin Ooooops! True. Just fixed it! :-)